# Swift access push on other ViewController

Tags: swift, push-notification, push, appdelegate

I have FirstViewController and SecondViewController. I'm trying to set push notifications. I added the following code in AppDelegate:

```
    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let notificationnSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationnSettings)
```

Users are given a request for access to the push notifications on the FirstViewController. All user have request on FirstViewController. But I want to they have request on the another ViewControllers or after specific actions. How to make that they receive it on the SecondViewController or after specific actions?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you register a notification the user will get it wether he is in your app or not. So you should only register the notification if you want the user to receive it. Or you should cancel it if you don't want him/her to receive it anymore. Maybe I didn't fully get your question...

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I still don't quite get your question. Do you mean that they should only have access to the second VC based on conditions? That could be done by disabling the button to send them there. Take a look at `segues` if that is your question (they can also send information from the first ViewController to the second)

Comment: No, I created push notification. I added code for request access to push settings in AppDelegate. It is OK. A request for access to push notifications is shown when the application was loaded on the FirstViewController. I want to show it not when I run the application but on a certain ViewController after certain actions.